# getElementById not selecting element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, dom, testing

I am trying to create an event based on the DOM for testing my Javascript skills, anyone knows why this isn't applying to the element?

```
function getButton(){
    var getButton = document.getElementById("submit");
    getButton.onclick() = function(){
         alert("it works!")
    }
}
```

Submit is an `<input type="submit" />` type of element from the element by Id, so I don't get it why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Drop the `()` in the event identifier. You are just assigning a property here and do not make a function call or similar.

```
function getButton(){

  var getButton = document.getElementById("submit");

  getButton.onclick = function(){
     alert("it works!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getButton.onclick = function() {
       alert("it works!");
};
```

Comment: ok i now gave to the submit element an id of "bla" and it still doesnt work.

Comment: ok i have found that only events seem not to work, can't imagine why, can the server block them?

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code:

1. The element you're trying to submit is a `<submit>` tag; it doesn't have `id="submit"`, so trying to get the element `getElementById("submit")` isn't going to work.

   Either give your `<submit>` tag its own `id` and select by that, or use `getElementByTagName("submit")` instead.
2. As the @Sirko and @Osiris have mentioned, `getButton.onclick() = function(){` isn't working because you're trying to call `.onclick()` as a function when it's not.  What you want to do is to assign a function to the `onclick` attribute of `getButton`:

   `getButton.onclick() = function(){` should be `getButton.onclick = function(){`.